# changing product urls -but I don't want to lose or hide existing likes?

Tags: url, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

As part of site restructuring (essentially SEO related improvements) one of my site's product urls are all going to change. Using ReWrite rules the products are changing from the current:
/[manufacturer]/products/[product_id].php to /[manufacturer]/[range]/[product_name].php

But I notice on the new pages that previous likes for these products are not showing. I have used the graph protocol to generate the like buttons, so I was hoping that if I kept the old URL in the meta tags  that they would link up to the old likes - unfortunately this is not happening.

Is there anyway to like my new product urls to their existing likes??

Comment: See also my answer on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-301-redirect-a-page-in-the-open-graph-and-retain-facebook-like-informa/10152342#10152342

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question is answered by this now inactive bug:

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18198

Essentially need to add the old urls in the href tag of the like button on your new page:

```
<fb:like href="http://[domain_name]/[old_path]" ></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add permanent redirect from old product URL to new, and show old likes (src to old url).

Comment: Hi, Anton thanks for your answer, but I am not sure if I understand what you are suggesting.  Of course the 'likes' will be visible on the old urls, but I want the customer to see them on the new urls?

Comment: No way to save old likes in another url.